# do a compare on 2 queries to find differences

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have two queries I'm trying to compare with each other. Both queries return the number of fields and same data. What I'm looking to do is be able to find which rows in either query don't exists in the other, so as an example (these queries are very much simplified, both queries have multiple joins)

Query1

```
Select Field1, Field2, Field3 
from Tbl1 
where date1 >='03/10/2020' and date1 <= '03/18/2020'
```

Q1 returns

```
 Field1  Field2  Field3
 --------------------------
 123     BAK     03/10/2020
 234     HAO     03/12/2020
```

Query 2

```
Select Field4, Field6, Field7 
from Tbl2 
where date1 >='03/10/2020' and date1 <= '03/18/2020'
```

Query 2 returns

```
Field4  Field6  Field7
--------------------------
123     BAK     03/10/2020
678     OID     03/17/2020
```

I need to join these queries on the three fields returned from each query Field1 = Field4, Field2 = Field6, Field3 = Field7 to be sure that only the data that doesn't have the exact match is returned.

My desired result would basically return all rows from query1 that don't have a corresponding row in query 2, and all rows from query2 that don't have a corresponding row in query1.

Desired result:

```
 234     HAO     03/12/2020 <--this exists in Query1 but not in Query2
 678     OID     03/17/2020 <-- this exists in Query2 but not in Query1
```

So what I did with this process is I created two common table expressions like so.... and then I used EXCEPT, but I'm trying to see if there's a better way.

```
WITH QueryA AS 
(
     Select Field1, Field2, Field3 
     from Tbl1 
     where date1 >='03/10/2020' and date1 <= '03/18/2020'
), 
QueryB AS 
(
     Select Field4, Field6, Field7 
     from Tbl2 
     where date1 >='03/10/2020' and date1 <= '03/18/2020'
)
```

Comment: Using `Except` seems to be the easiest way. How did that query end up?
A except B union B except A should do it.

Comment: `Except` is built for this purpose. So when you say "better way", do you mean performance or elegance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `full join` -- assuming no columns are `NULL`:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from (Select Field1, Field2, Field3 
      from Tbl1 
      where date1 >= '2020-03-10' and date1 <= '2020-03-18' 
     ) t1 full join
     (Select Field4, Field6, Field7 
      from Tbl2 
      where date1 >= '2020-03-10' and date1 <= '2020-03-18'
     ) t2
     on t1.field1 = t2.field4 and t1.field2 = t2.field5 and
        t1.field3 = t2.field7
where t1.field1 is null or t2.field4 is null;
```

Another method is `union all`:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from ((Select Field1, Field2, Field3, 1 as in_1, 0 as in_2
       from Tbl1 
       where date1 >= '2020-03-10' and date1 <= '2020-03-18' 
      ) t1 full join
      (Select Field4, Field6, Field7, 0, 1
       from Tbl2 
       where date1 >= '2020-03-10' and date1 <= '2020-03-18'
      )
     ) t12
group by field1, field2, field3
having sum(in_1) = sum(in_2);
```

Note that this has two advantages over the previous method:

1. It handles `NULL` values in the columns.
2. It handles duplicates -- and validates the same number of duplicates are in both tables.

Answer (score 1):

Use `UNION` :

```
Select Field1, Field2, Field3 
from Tbl1 
where date1 >= '2020-03-10' and date1 <= '2020-03-18' 
UNION
Select Field4, Field6, Field7 
from Tbl2 
where date1 >= '2020-03-10' and date1 <= '2020-03-18';
```

`FULL OUTER JOIN` will also helpful :

```
SELECT COALESCE(t1.Field1, t2.Field4),
       COALESCE(t1.Field2, t2.Field6),
       COALESCE(t1.Field3 , t2.Field7)
FROM Tbl1 t1 FULL OUTER JOIN
     Tbl2 t2
     on t1.field1 = t2.field4 and t1.field2 = t2.Field6 and
        t1.field3 = t2.field7
WHERE (t1.field1 is null or t2.field4 is null);
```

Answer (score 1):

I was playing with some dummy data to see if you could achieve this using 2 `left joins`. See if it helps

```
with cte1 (name, id) as

(select 'brad', 1 union all
select 'john',2),

cte2 (name, id) as
(select 'brad', 1 union all
select 'jack',3)

select a.name, a.id, 'missing in cte2' as status
from cte1 a left join cte2 b on a.name=b.name
where b.name is null
union
select a.name, a.id, 'missing in cte1' as status
from cte2 a left join cte1 b on a.name=b.name
where b.name is null
```

If you really want to use `except`, you could do

```
select name, id, 'missing in cte2' as status from cte1 
except
select name, id, 'missing in cte2' as status from cte2
union
select name, id, 'missing in cte1' as status from cte2
except
select name, id, 'missing in cte1' as status from cte1
```

Comment: Hi thanks i see what you are doing. I was thinking about doing something along what you did, with adding the "missing".

Comment: If you need that the additional column to flag the missing, this or potentially other `joins` bases approaches might be the way to go

Comment: looks like I would want to display the missing text. but i feel like your approach is very verbose. Is there any way to achieve that with EXCEPT OR UNION? I'd maybe want to do something like Select Val1, Val2, Val3, 'MISS'='Missing in query2' and then either do EXCEPT or UNION and do the same in Query 2, so only returned rows would have the three values, and either Missing in queyr2 or missing in query1

Comment: something like a UNION but exclude the MISSING column from each SELECT statement if i use the approach in my earlier comment

Comment: @Koosh See my update. That's as less verbose as I can think of

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that works for comparing data from two tables/views/datasets

```
select x.field1
      ,x.field2
      ,x.field3
      ,count(qry_1) as present_in_qry1
      ,count(qry_2) as present_in_qry2
  from (Select Field1, Field2, Field3 , 1 as qry_1, null as qry_2
          from Tbl1 
         where date1 >='03/10/2020' and date1 <= '03/18/2020'
        union all
        Select Field4, Field6, Field7, null as qry_1, 1 as qry_2
          from Tbl2 
         where date1 >= '2020-03-10' and date1 <= '2020-03-18'
        )x
group by x.field1
        ,x.field2
        ,x.field3
having count(qry_1) <> count(qry_2)
order by 1,2,3
```